# Is it possible to specify an entrypoint in the kubectl cloud builder?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, docker-entrypoint

With the [docker cloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/docker) I am able to specify an entry point to `bash` or `sh` like so:

> **`cloudbuild.yaml`**
>
> ```
> steps:
>   - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
>     id: BuildDockerImages
>     entrypoint: /bin/sh
>     args:
>       - '-c'
>       - |
>         set -x && \
>         ./build_and_push_images.sh
>     env:
>       - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a'
>       - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=standard-cluster-1'
> ```

---

But whatever shell program (`bash` or `sh`) I specify in the `entrypoint` of the [kubectl cloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/kubectl), I receive the following error in cloudbuild:

> ```
> Step #2 - "UpdateImages": docker: Error response from daemon: OCI
>  runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container
>  process caused "exec: \"sh - '-c' - | set -x && \\\\ echo hi\":
>  executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
> ```

This being the config:

> **`cloudbuild.yaml`**
>
> ```
>  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
>     id: UpdateImages
>     entrypoint: sh # or bash, /bin/sh, /bin/bash
>       - '-c'
>       - |
>         set -x && \
>         ./devops/update_k8s_deployment.sh
>     env:
>       - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a'
>       - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=standard-cluster-1'
> ```

Am I missing something? Why am I not able to specify an entry point? Do I need to use another builder and install kubectl everytime myself?

Comment: @ChrisF♦ deleted my answer to this question. The issue with the above config is that the [args](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#args) section is missing. Sorry

Comment: example "Best practices for speeding up builds"
 [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds)